# Back button triggering stopped unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've had an incredibly difficult time getting the below app to not show an error when the back button is pressed.  All I want is the site to load a web page and the back button to perform as it normally does.  Does anyone see anything wrong here?  The LogCat shows no errors and with the emulator it doesn't break, but it always breaks on my tablet.

**MyWebViewClient.java**

```
package com.MySite;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MySite.java**

```
package com.mysite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MySite extends Activity {
    WebView DCWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //init webview
        WebView DCWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        DCWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        DCWebView.loadUrl("http://mobile.mysite.com");

        //when a link is clicked, use the WebView instead of opening a new browser
        DCWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && DCWebView.canGoBack()) {
            DCWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a local variable called `DCWebView` inside of `onCreate()`. Change the line

```
WebView DCWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

to

```
DCWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Then, when the back key is pressed, there will be a back stack (which is currently false when you call `DCWebView.canGoBack()`, since your global `DCWebView` was never initialized), the back button will be handled the way you are expecting.

Comment: Are you saying by putting `WebView` there I'm defining it as global?

Comment: To reply to your first comment, when you declared the `DCWebView` inside your method, it `overrided` the global variable of the same name. Thus, that was the `DCWebView` you were using inside the method - not the one you meant to be using.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting when you hit back on a tablet?  Have you tried overriding onBackPressed instead of onKeyDown?

Comment: Should I just put `this.finish()` within onBackPressed?

Comment: If you want the activity to close and return to the former activity (whatever you launched DealClippings from) then calling finish() should do that, yes.

Comment: The default functionality of onBackPressed is to execute finish(), so defining that within my own app won't do anything :-\

Comment: Can you clarify what the desired functionality is when the user taps the back button?  Also, are you able to connect your tablet to the computer and check Logcat in DDMS to see what error it's recording?